# cannot find symbol class LoginActivityError

Tags: android-studio

I am making an app and I have a button that  says Sign in and when you click on the button it is supposed to redirect you to a new page that will have you sign in. When i clicked New>Activity and selected a log in page and clicked finish there was an error that says Cannot Find Symbol Class Login Activity. Heres the location of the error in code:

```
private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
   //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
                    emailAddressCollection);
   mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Comment: include you complete LoginActivity code, is it complaining errors at beginning as well ?

Comment: i am having the same error and I also don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager (**Tools** menu > **Android**), and install **Android Support Repository** in **Extras**. After this you may need to click the **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button in the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just starting, and I had the same issue.

I added the login activity using Android Studio's wizard, but I didn't use the default activity name.

When the class was generated, it referenced to "LoginActivity.this", using the default name.
In my case, I just needed to replace the Activity name for the one I've used while creating it.

Example:
new ArrayAdapter( "ActualNameOfLoginActivity" .this...